# Where should I put background images in different screensizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I've been reading about the `drawable-XXdpi` folders, and I created my icons in all sizes.

What I want to do now, is to put a background image on my main screen. And what my assumption is at this moment, is that I don't work with `DP` at this moment but with `PX`, because my background image needs to fill all the `pixels`.

**When this assumption is correct, where do I put my created background images?**

I've created one for `480*320`, `800*400` to the largest `1600x2560`.
In my assumption I can't put them in the `drawable-XXdpi` folders because those are `DPI` related, and I need to fill all the `pixels`.

Comment: I would put it in the `drawable` folder (non- dpi related), but not sure if its the best practice

Comment: @Der Golem: shouldn't I create a background with the exact pixel size instead of using a stretched image?

Comment: @Der Golem: Thanks! Can you make your comments an answer? Your comments made clear that I should not use px.

Comment: Ok, done. Hopefully it will help others, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I don't work with DP at this moment but with PX` ... You should **always** use DP.
To fill all the available space, just use `android:background` instead of `android:src`.

Note that the image will be stretched (if you don't make it a [9 patch](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) - this will also be stretched, but in a "controlled manner").

---

To `create a background with the exact pixel size` is not a good practice.
You'd end up wit oversized images.

Better practices include (not mutually exclusive - they can be stacked by using a [Layer-List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)):

- stretchables (such as 9 patches)
- tiles (seamlessly tileable pictures)
- drawables (which are vectorial, like SVG files)
  These ones include:
  a - shapes
  b - gradients
  c - ...
- SVG (through 3rd party libraries)
- ...

Also consider that "the exact pixel size" might be different from what you expect.
You have to take in account the StatusBar, the ActionBar/ToolBar, the MenuBar, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can put your drawable that is not specific for each dpi into     drawable-nodpi     folder.
But basically, as Der Golem describes, you should always use dp.

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate folder architecture for putting px files. You need to use drawable-hdpi , drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi.

Answer (score 1):

The approximate pixel values for different dps are like this:

```
ldpi    = 600.00px x 360.00px
mdpi    = 800.00px x 480.00px
hdpi    = 1200.00px x 720.00px
xhdpi   = 1600.00px x 960.00px
xxhdpi  = 2400.00px x 1440.00px
```

Check these links for more details:

http://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html